# Why doesn't rep gained after cap cover for rep lost after cap (in a single day)?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Suppose someone reached the rep cap for a certain day, and after that they got, say, `4` upvotes (`+40` rep), because of the rep cap, those won't be counted, but if someone downvotes one of their posts, they will recieve a `-2` rep (resulting in the user having `+198` rep for that day), why doesn't that `+40` rep cover for the `-2` since it's in the same day, what is the rational behind this decision?

Comment: Probably for the same reason that if you have -5 votes on an answer, a single +1 after those still gives OP +10 rep rather than having it canceled out by the -10 from the earlier downvotes.

Comment: It's worth noting that if there are any upvotes after the downvote, they take you back up to the cap. So it's only if the *final* vote of the day is a downvote that it causes a problem.

Comment: (That's pretty rare in my experience - it's happened to me 6 times in 11 years.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184318) by Ben Collins, a [former SO employee](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/07/01/say-hi-to-nine-of-our-newest-newbies/):

> I spent some time looking at this (with @NickCraver), and there's just not a reasonable way for us to calculate this sort of negative-rep backfill in realtime efficiently, and it makes a pretty substantial mess of historical rep calculations (i.e., questions being closed causes a reputation recalc).
>
> ...
>
> It's just that this particular behavior is an edge case that exceedingly few users will experience – and the impact is pretty minimal for users who do – and we just can't justify the effort required to calculate rep in the suggested manner.

Comment: It seems fair to me anyway even if it could be changed. If the overflow would still act as a sort of secret reserve which will be used to counteract the effects of downvotes... that will start to look like downvotes have no effect on the few people that will have such reserves.